# mule - web service consumer (soap) always returns null

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, mule, dataweave

I am using the Zuora soap API.  I am attempting to perform a query.  I don't get any errors but the results are always null when I output the payload to log.  What am I doing wrong? (the query I provide below should return 320 records, which is what I get if I execute the same query in a local non-mule test script)

This is the section of the flow.

[image]

1. I set the zoql query to flowVars (flowVars.query).  For example : `select id from Account WHERE updatedDate > '2016-06-24T23:00:00-06:00'`
2. I use dataweave to create the xml payload (dw provided below)
3. I execute the query (web service consumer app xml details provided below)

**DataWeave to set payload:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://api.zuora.com/
---
{
    ns0#query: {
        ns0#queryString: flowVars.query
    }
}
```

**Web Service Consumer app xml**

`<ws:consumer config-ref="ZuoraWebServiceConsumer" operation="query" doc:name="query_zuora"/>`

**ZuoraWebServiceConsumer config details:**

```
<ws:consumer-config name="ZuoraWebServiceConsumer" wsdlLocation="zuora.a.49.0-sandbox.wsdl" service="ZuoraService" port="Soap" serviceAddress="https://apisandbox-api.zuora.com" doc:name="Web Service Consumer">
    <ws:security>
        <ws:wss-username-token username="myusername.here" password="mypassword.here" passwordType="TEXT" />
    </ws:security>
</ws:consumer-config>
```

**And the WSDL:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fkrppvv7i5s1a4w/zuora.a.49.0-sandbox.wsdl?dl=0

Comment: Could you please add your mule log as well? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with MuleSoft Support, it was discovered there is a bug with the Zuora connector.  When Zuora returns an invalid session error, the Zuora connector is not catching it, destroying the connection from the pool, and initiating a new connection.  MuleSoft has confirmed the bug.